# Is there a cd available for download?

Tags: system-installation

I've got an old Dell d630 that's running xp and I want to use ubnutu on it. It seems to be a 32 bit machine and have been trying to boot it up from a flash drive with no success.

Comment: Alternatively, use the [minimal image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

Answer (score 2):

The Dell D630 should be able to boot from a USB stick, if you prepared the stick properly.

Possible issues:

- USB drive draws too much power (some 8GB+ drives do) - solution: [put a powered USB hub in between](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19209785).
- Image file is not put on USB Stick properly - solution: use a program in Windows to put image file (.iso) onto drive, for instance using [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

If these are not your issues, you may need to use a DVD (not a CD, won't fit) to install Ubuntu. I would suggest using the LTS (14.04) with that laptop, which you can download from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=14.04.3&architecture=i386) - you can download the file and use a program (e.g. CDBurnerXP, etc) to burn to DVD (instructions are available [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)).

Also, after installing you might need to spend some time trying to fix up the networking part of the laptop (I have a D640, took some time to get the Broadcom chip to work) but it is possible to have Ubuntu working on it.

Enjoy!